# How to render a react component in sweetalert2 innerhtml?

Tags: reactjs, sweetalert

This is my code which i want render `CarReport` component in a sweetalert modal. `<CarReport />` is just a simple form.

```js
Swal.fire({
        title: "..."
        html: <CarReport />, //How to write this line?
        confirmButtonText: "Check",
        preConfirm: () => {
            //api request
        },
      });
```

Currently this code opens the modal but shows [object object] in body of the modal.

Answer (score 1):

SweetAlert2 does not support react components. For that it requires using

[sweetalert2-react-content](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2-react-content)